# best way to transfer weights? (clothing)

Tags: weight-painting

What is the best or most functional way to transfer a character's weight to an outfit? I end up using transfer weights with nearest face interpolated but I end up having a lot of problems

Comment: Hello have you tried the Data Transfer modifier? You need to choose the Source, then enable Vertex Data, click on Vertex Groups, and choose Mapping > Nearest Vertex, click on Generate Data Layers and apply the modifier

Comment: Hi!! Thanks! I will try and tell you the result+